# Replacing Text with Error Message if Text not Found in Matlab

Tags: matlab, replace

I have a function that replaces a piece of text, and it became relevant that this function needs to issue an error in case it fails to do so.

One way to do so would be:

```
text_var = 'The whole big text';
if(~contains(text_var,'The part that will be replaced')))
     throw(MException('MF:error','The part to be replaced is not in the text!'))
else
     text_var = strrep(text_var,'The part that will be replaced','The replacement');
end
```

However, this seems not to be efficient. I can assume the text, if it appears does so only once. But I'd like to make a single call to a function operating on `text_var`. Is there no text replacement function in Matlab that returns an error if the replacement failed?

Comment: if you store your new string in a new variable `text_var_new = strrep(...` you can then use `strcmp` to compare if both variable are similar, I guess that strcmp will be more efficient than `contains`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the replace, and just check if the new string's length is unchanged (this assumes the original and replacement strings are different lengths)

```
text_var = 'the whole big text';
n = numel( text_var );
text_var = strrep( text_var, 'replace me', 'with this' );
if numel( text_var ) == n
    error( 'No replacements made' );
end
```

If you can't make that assumption, you could use `strfind` to get the indices of the string. This will be empty if not found (so error), or you can use it to manually remove the string. Especially easy as you state it will appear at most once.

```
text_var = 'the whole big text';
removeStr = 'replace this';
k = strfind( text_var, removeStr );
if isempty( k )
    error( 'No replacements made' );
end
text_var( k:k+numel(removeStr)-1 ) = []; % Remove string
```

Because you're only matching once, you *might* find that `regexp` is quicker than `strfind`, as you can use the `'once'` argument of `regexp` to make it stop on the first match

```
k = regexp( text_var, removeStr, 'once' ); % instead of using strfind
```

Comment: I accepted the answer as it should provide good output to whoever finds this in the future. I, however, am required not to have warnings in my code, hence I'm motivated to accept Matlab's suggestion to use `contains` instead of `k = strfind( text_var, removeStr ); if isempty( k )...`.

Comment: @Mefitco you could use `regexp` as I suggested, you won't get any warnings and it could be quicker. Or just surpress the code analyser warning - you know it's not a performance hit in this use case because of why I used `strfind`